# Scroll-behaviour Effect

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement a Scroll-Effect but it's only working partially . When I scroll-down its working, but when I scroll up it's a straight jump.

```css
html{
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
section{
  height:100vh;
  margin:0;
  padding:10px;
  
}
navbar{
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<navbar>
  <a href="#welcome"><b>ABOUT</b></a>
  <a href="#project"><b>PROJECT</b></a>
</navbar>
<section id="Welcome" style="background-color:black;color:White;">
  <h1>
  Hi This is Akhil!
  </h1>
</section>
<section id="project" style="background-color:Red;color:white;">
  <h1>
  This is project section
  </h1>
</section>
```

Comment: Seems smooth in both directions to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you're using the tag `<navbar>` which isn't a valid tag in HTML. Because of this, it's causing your scroll-behaviour to function in an undesired way.

Instead, you should be using the [`<nav>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav) tag, which is a valid tag (you'll need to change your CSS to work with the `nav` tag rather than the `navbar` tag). Also, make sure that both your `href` and `id` for the section you want to scroll to match exactly (case matters)

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#welcome"><b>ABOUT</b></a>
  <a href="#project"><b>PROJECT</b></a>
</nav>

<section id="welcome" style="background-color:black;color:white;">
  <h1>
    Hi This is Akhil!
  </h1>
</section>
<section id="project" style="background-color:red;color:white;">
  <h1>
    This is project section
  </h1>
</section>
```

Comment: @AkhilRaj did you also change the `id` of "welcome" to be lowercase?

Comment: Thanks @Nick Parsons  part of it was navbar to nav  and and case error. But , what is the HTML 5 semantic tag though? nav or navbar

Comment: @AkhilRaj `<navbar>` isn't a HTML tag. You should use `<nav>`

Answer (score 0):

Your `<a href="#welcome"><b>WELCOME</b></a>` is lower case, try capitalisig to match your Id.

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('a[rel="relativeanchor"]').click(function(){
     $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
     }, 800);
     return false;
 }); 
});
```

```css
html{
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
section{
  height:100vh;
  margin:0;
  padding:10px;
  
}
navbar{
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="top">How to make smooth scrolling.</h1>

<a href="#mysection1" rel="relativeanchor">Section 1</a>
<a href="#mysection2" rel="relativeanchor">Section 2</a>

<div style="height: 1500px;">This requires jQuery. <a href="#top" rel="relativeanchor">Go Back to Top</a></div>

<div id="mysection1">Section 1</div>


<div style="height: 1500px;">This requires jQuery. <a href="#top" rel="relativeanchor">Go Back to Top</a></div>
    


<div id="mysection2">Section 2</div>

    <a href="#top" rel="relativeanchor">Go Back to Top</a>
```

Hope this may help you. You work around with your code.

Here is the [reference](http://jsfiddle.net/francescov/4DcNH/)